# JavaFX click through ImageView

Tags: javafx-2

I want to click through a component like ImageView.

```
  ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png")));
  //What function to use to click through iv ?
```

I try this but still don't work

```
iv.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a node to receive mouse events, make it [mouse transparent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent%28boolean%29).

```
imageView.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

Comment: still I can't click through

Comment: It works for me.  Edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates what doesn't work for you.